# Sample vs Population Covariance Matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance, estimation, upper-lower-bounds

Let $P(X)$ be a probability density function over $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and assume its random variable $X$ to have a zero mean and a covariance matrix:
$\Sigma = cov(X, X) = \mathbb{E}[XX^T]$
In case of kernel PCA methods, $X$ is actually the feature vector of the original data point, and $n$ may be finite or infinite depending on the associated kernel.

Let $\{ X_i \}_{i = 1}^{N}$ to be i.i.d. samples from $P(X)$, and define estimator of $\Sigma$ as:
$\hat{\Sigma} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} X_i X_i^T$

Let $\{ \lambda_j, v_j \}$ and $\{ \hat{\lambda}_j, \hat{v}_j \}$ be eigenpairs of $\Sigma$ and $\hat{\Sigma}$ respectively, where eigenvalues are sorted in decreasing order.

How close are $n \times n$ matrices $\Sigma$ and $\hat{\Sigma}$? How close are their eigenvalues $\{ \lambda_j \}$ and $\{ \hat{\lambda}_j \}$, and eigenvectors $\{ v_j \}$ and $\{ \hat{v}_j \}$? Specifically, can we lower-upper bound the inner product $<v_k, \hat{v}_m>^2$ more tightly than the obvious $[0, 1]$ interval?

---

Below I summarize several papers that answer some parts of my question. If anyone has more suggestions, please share them below.

Comment: As partial answer, I found this paper: https://eprints.soton.ac.uk/259779/1/OnTheEigenspectrumOfTheGramMatrix.pdf

Comment: It provides relationship of eigenvalues between two corresponding matrices. But is there anything about eigenvectors? Also, the paper is from 2005. Are there any updated papers on the topic?

Comment: If you are at an institution that has access, chapters 6 and 8 of [this text](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E) discuss this. For eigenvalues, you can also see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3484.pdf) (see also Section 4.7 of [his book](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf)). There also seems to be [this paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/loukas17a/loukas17a.pdf) for eigenvectors, although I have not read it.

Comment: Great, thanks! after reading them, I'll add a short summary here for the related material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I add short summary of papers I found to be relevant for the above questions.

Denote by $V_k$ and $\hat{V}_k$ sub-spaces that correspond to spans of $\{ v_j \}_{j = 1}^{k}$ and $\{ \hat{v}_j \}_{j = 1}^{k}$ respectively. Denote by $P_k$ and $\hat{P}_k$ the orthogonal projectors on these sub-spaces. Finally, denote by $V_k^{\perp}$ and $\hat{V}_k^{\perp}$ the orthogonal complements of $V_k$ and $\hat{V}_k$.

1. [John Shawe-Taylor,2005](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/ckiw/postscript/gram.pdf) produces probabilistic bounds on eigenvalue sums, i.e. $\sum_{j = 1}^{k} \lambda_j$. Additionally, there are bounds on projection of new data onto $\hat{V}_k$ and onto $\hat{V}_k^{\perp}$. Finally, it gives bounds on $\hat{v}_j^T \Sigma \hat{v}_j$.
2. [Laurent Zwald, 2006](http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Laurent.Zwald/paper/Nips2005mod.pdf) bounds Hilbert-Schmidt norm of a differences $\Sigma - \hat{\Sigma}$ and $P_k - \hat{P}_k$. Likewise, there is bound on $<v_k, \hat{v}_k>^2$.
3. [Gilles Blanchard, 2007](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewainwrig/stat241b/KPCA_revision_final.pdf) there are bounds on projection of new data onto $V_k^{\perp}$ and onto $\hat{V}_k^{\perp}$. Likewise, bounds produced to relate sums $\sum_{j = k}^{n} \lambda_j$ and $\sum_{j = k}^{n} \hat{\lambda}_j$. This work refines some of the results of 1.
4. [Roman Vershynin, 2010](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3484.pdf) bounds operator norm of $\Sigma - \hat{\Sigma}$, showing that this norm is small with high probability when $N = O(n)$ and the distribution has finite fourth moment.
5. [Lorenzo Rosasco, 2010](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/%7Ebelkin.8/papers/LIO_JMLR_10.pdf) bounds $\sum_{j \geq 1} (\lambda_j - \hat{\lambda}_j)^2$, $\sup_{j \geq 1} (\lambda_j - \hat{\lambda}_j)^2$, and $|tr(\Sigma) - tr(\hat{\Sigma})|$.
6. [Andreas Louka, 2017](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/loukas17a/loukas17a.pdf) bounds $|<v_k, \hat{v}_m>|$ for any $k$ and $m$, showing its bound to be inverse proportional to $|\lambda_k - \lambda_m|$. Further, a probabilistic version of this bound is proposed relating expressions $|<v_k, \hat{v}_m>|$ and $|\lambda_k - \hat{\lambda}_k|$ with a measure of the concentration of the distribution in
   the direction of $v_k$.
7. [Wainwright Martin J, book, 2019](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E) bounds 2-norm of $\Sigma - \hat{\Sigma}$ (Section 6), and $||v_1 - \hat{v}_1||_2$ (Section 8). Also, some theorems are provided especially for sparse covariance matrices.